# Written unit test for testing rxjava, but not sure if my unit test is testing everything

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

```
Android Studio 3.4
```

I have the following method that I am testing. Basically, what this test does is makes a request and that will return a `LoginResponseEntity` that will be mapped and return a `Single<LoginResponse>`

```
 override fun loginUserPost(username: String, password: String, uniqueIdentifier: String, deviceToken: String, apiToken: String) : Single<LoginResponse> {
            val loginRequestEntity = LoginRequestEntity(username, password, uniqueIdentifier, deviceToken)
            return loginAPIService.loginUserPost(loginRequestEntity, apiToken)
                .map {
                    loginResponseDomainMapper.map(it)
                }
    }
```

The test case I have written works, but I think that this is not fully testing this method.

```
     @Test
     fun `should return LoginResponse`() {
        val loginRequestEntity = LoginRequestEntity("username", "password", "uniqueidentifier", "devicetoken")
        val loginResponse = LoginResponse("token", createUser(), emptyList(), emptyList())
        val loginResponseEntity = LoginResponseEntity("token", createUserEntity(), emptyList(), emptyList())

        whenever(loginAPIService.loginUserPost(loginRequestEntity, "apitoken")).thenReturn(Single.just(loginResponseEntity))

        loginServiceImp.loginUserPost("username", "password", "uniqueidentifier", "devicetoken", "apitoken")
            .test()
            .assertValue(loginResponse)

        verify(loginAPIService).loginUserPost(loginRequestEntity, "apitoken")
    }

        private fun createUser() =
            User(
                "id",
                "email",
                "firstname",
                "lastname",
                "phone",
                "address",
                "dob",
                "customer",
                listOf("enterpriseids"),
                listOf("vendorids"))

        private fun createUserEntity() =
            UserEntity(
                "id",
                "email",
                "firstname",
                "lastname",
                "phone",
                "address",
                "dob",
                "customer",
                listOf("enterpriseids"),
                listOf("vendorids"))
    }
```

Is there anything more I can do to test this method. Should I be testing the `.map{loginResponseDomainMapper.map(it)` part of this method?

Comment: usually the first thing you test is the result of the function. You can do this with a TestScheduler

Comment: Unless you use some sort of code coverage tool, you will never know if your code is fully tested, you can try `jacoco` or even `idea` has one included

Comment: You're only testing the happy path. What about if the `loginAPIService.loginUserPost()` method fails?

Answer (score 1):

This is really small method and doesn't contain a lot of things to test. Two external dependencies (`loginAPIService` and `loginResponseDomainMapper`) reduce amount of things to test even more.

So,

1) `loginResponseDomainMapper` is not a part of tested method and should also be mocked.

2) You have to understand, what should be tested here.

- First: check if `LoginRequestEntity` was correctly constructed and passed to `loginUserPost` method. This is done by `verify(loginAPIService).loginUserPost(loginRequestEntity, "apitoken")` call. Additionally you can use [`ArgumentCaptor`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).
- Second: Output of `loginUserPost` method was correctly passed to `loginResponseDomainMapper.map` method. This could be done with additional `verify` call as previously.
- Third: Output of map method was correctly returned. This is done by `assertValue` call.

So, you are just trying to verify that the dataflow was correct and nothing was modified during execution by the aliens or something like that.

3) Negative testing. There are also not many things that can go wrong. If `loginUserPost` doesn't have a `@NotNull` annotation, you better to handle `null` result of this function.
Also, what if request was incorrect? Password was wrong, or `apitoken` has expired? I believe that this will not lead to sad consequences, but you should to thing about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add tests for unsuccessful scenarios:

1) If `loginUserPost` fails, you can add:

```
whenever(loginAPIService.loginUserPost(any(), any())).thenReturn(Single.error(Exception()))
...
   .test()
   .assertError(...)
```

2) If `loginResponseDomainMapper` fails, you can add:

```
whenever(loginResponseDomainMapper.map(any())).thenThrow(Exception())
...
       .test()
       .assertError(...)
```

This way you can test unsuccessful / successful mapping and function output without going into details. `loginResponseDomainMapper` behaviour should be tested in scope of its own unit tests.